# Clique em subitem do menu traz id do nível acima

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um menu onde ao clicar nele eu envio um código para uma página, esta página ela redireciona para a página que foi setada com aquele `id`. Até este ponto está funcionando só que quando eu clico no submenu, ele me traz o código do pai dele.

```
carregarPaginas();

function carregarPaginas() {
    $(".subitem").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var acao = $(this).find('.acao').html();
        location.href = 'includes/publicacao.php?c=' + acao;
    });

    $(".menuLi").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var acao = $(this).find('.acao').html();
        location.href = 'includes/publicacao.php?c=' + acao;
    });
};
```

Aqui vem a estrutura do menu:

```
<li class="menuLi">
    <div class="acao">-3</div>
    <div class="desc">Servicos</div>
    <div class="submenuC">
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="subitem">
                <div class="acao">-4</div>
                <div class="desc">Downloads</div>
            </li>
            <li class="subitem">
                <div class="acao">-5</div>
                <div class="desc">Videos</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Testa juntar `e.stopPropagation();` dentro de `$(".subitem").click(function (e) {`

Comment: Tenta o que o @Sergio comentou, e também selecionar `.acao` como filho direto de `.menuLi` e `.submenu`. Voce pode fazer  `var acao = $(' > .acao', this).html()`

Comment: vlw deu certinho. faz uma resposta para min aceita-la.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira e So que agora o segundo li do sub menu não funciona.

Comment: Qual é o "segundo li do sub menu"? está no teu exemplo?

Comment: Agora está veja la

Comment: Funciona bem para mim: http://jsfiddle.net/37p2crxs/

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar.

Comment: Pela resposta que aceitas-te diz-me que não percebeste o problema....

Comment: Mais funcionou e outra foi o único que me deu uma resposta completa.

Comment: Tem alguma solução melhor @Sergio ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues a minha resposta em baixo. Com exemplo no jsFiddle que coloquei aqui nos coments (http://jsfiddle.net/37p2crxs/).

Comment: Agora deu certo, obrigado novamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando clicas no elemento filho o evento sobe no DOM e dispara também o evento `click` no pai (`.menuLi`).

Assim tens de impedir que ele se propague com `e.stopPropagation();` e portanto não dispare o evento do elemento pai.

O código ficaria assim:

```
$('.subitem').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // resto do código...
```

Comment: Obrigado por ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que quando você clica em um subitem, você também está clicando no menu. Por isso, você previsa validar o item clicado

```
carregarPaginas();

            function carregarPaginas() {
                $(".subitem").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var acao = $(this).find('.acao').html();
                    location.href = 'includes/publicacao.php?c=' + acao;
                });

                $(".menuLi").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(ehDescendenteDeSubItem(e.target)) return;

                    var acao = $(this).find('.acao').html();
                    location.href = 'includes/publicacao.php?c=' + acao;
                });
            }

function ehDescendenteDeSubItem(e){
    return $(e).parent().attr('class') === 'subitem'
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado o seu funcionou perfeitamente. e com todas as particularidades.

Comment: Esta resposta implica que `$(e).parent().attr('class') === 'subitem'` só verifica `true` se `$(e).parent()` só tiver uma classe. Se tiver mais classes isso vai dar `false` (solução: `hasClass('subitem')`) . E no caso de `. acao` via a ter um `span` por exemplo o código vai encontrar o `.parent()` errado (solucão: `.closest('li')`).

Comment: Você tem razão, Sergio, eu acabei não validando todas as possibilidades. Mas, o foco era a explicação quanto à validação do item clicado, para os casos específicos (e/ou mais gerais), acredito que agora ele conseguirá implementar.